# Как сделать так, чтобы сервер был всегда запущен? CentOS 7

Tags: python, django

Сейчас Я прописываю

```
python manage.py runserver 0:80
```

И в ответ получаю:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 08, 2015 - 20:12:09
Django version 1.8, using settings 'butlers.settings'
Starting development server at http://0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[08/Apr/2015 20:12:24]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2239
[08/Apr/2015 20:12:24]"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2272
[08/Apr/2015 20:12:30]"GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[08/Apr/2015 20:12:30]"GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22
[08/Apr/2015 20:13:27]"GET /admin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 2267
[08/Apr/2015 20:13:27]"GET /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.0" 404 2309
[08/Apr/2015 20:13:27]"GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 404 2276
```

Если Я закрываю консоль(putty) или нажимаю contol-c, запросы прекращают доходить. То бишь, браузер отдаёт 404. Посоветуйте, что сделать, чтобы сервер работал автономно. И правильный ли это вариант работы сервера? Мне почему-то кажется, что всё идёт в обход nginx'а(чувствую запах идиотизма).

Использую uwsgi, хотя так же не понял, что это такое, какая-то прослойка. Если можно, хотелось бы и здесь получить развёрнутый ответ. Я новичок в python'e. Решил уйти с пыхи.

Крутится всё это на vps. CentOS 7.

Comment: А зачем тебе django? У тебя судя по всем WordPress, который работает на php...

Comment: Вопрос в заголовке необъятный. Подсказка для скрытого конкетного вопроса: существует множество пошаговых руководств о том *как развернуть сайт на django*, например рекомендуемый документацией [apache+mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi) или из гугла одна из первых ссылок: [nginx + gunicorn on aws/ec2](http://rogueleaderr.com/post/65157477648/the-idiomatic-guide-to-deploying-django-in)

Comment: К Toly. Что ты несёшь?

Comment: @ashalbulk там приходят весьма характерные для вордпресса запросы. Другое дело, что возвращается 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов решения проблему.

Например, можно использовать внешний сервер Apache со следующей конфигурацией:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Подробнее:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ (англ.)

Но мне больше нравится связка Nginx + gunicorn:

```
server {

  server_name 127.0.0.1 yourhost@example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;

    # This line is important as it tells nginx to channel all requests to port 8000.
    # We will later run our wsgi application on this port using gunicorn.
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  }

}
```

Запсукаем приложение с помощью gunicorn:

```
$ sudo pip install gunicorn  # инсталлируем gunicorn
$ cd /path/to/yourproject
$ gunicorn wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --pid /tmp/gunicorn.pid --daemon
```

Подробнее об этом:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163233/ (англ.)

Answer (score 2):

UWSGI (как и gunicorn) - это прослойка для запуска приложений на python. Запускать на боевом веб-сервере сервер разработки ни в коем случае нельзя: во-первых он однопоточный, что как минимум сильно его замедляет, во-вторых предназначен для тестирования и отладки, а не для боевой нагрузки. Конечно, если очень хочется, то его можно запустить как-то вроде `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 --insecure`, но это максимум для проверки, что всё работает. К тому же подобная команда запускается от имени суперпользователя, что тоже **очень плохо для боевого сервера**. Никогда ничего нельзя запускать с повышенными привилегиями.

UWSGI же позволяет запускать сервер в несколько обработчиков потоков, ограничивает по потребляемым ресурсам, следит за временем выполнения и ещё много чего. Поэтому вам лучше всего воспользоваться статьями, описывающими настройку веб-приложений для работы через uwsgi или ginicorn. От себя советую [вот эту статью](http://eshlox.net/2012/09/11/nginx-uwsgi-virtualenv-and-django-ubuntu-1204/)

Comment: ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 --insecure  - у меня такая конструкция работает. Но Я почему-то не вижу никакого присутствия nginx'a. Это работает как-то в обход?

Comment: Вам не надо на боевом сервере запускать проект через runserver. UWSGI работает **не** через него. В файле конфигурации UWSGI для вашего проекта (напр. ```/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/proj.ini```) надо указать wsgi файл вашего проекта в джанге (он лежит в корневой директории), корневой путь проекта и chroot окружение (virtualenv, ксли он используется). Также в нём вы указываете socket файл (например, /tmp/proj.sock) через который и будет происходить общение веб-сервера с вашим проектом. В интернете [довольно неплохо освещена](http://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/) эта тема

Comment: С gunicorn примерно такая же история?

Comment: [В точности](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html). Разве что немного отличается параметрами. Многие советуют запускать их под supervisor, но в ubuntu, например, есть скрипты, которые запускают их как демонов. По своему опыту могу сказать, что решение достаточно надёжное (возможно в centos тоже есть). Плюс supervisor в том, что он сам умеет перезапускать упавшие под его контролем программы, но на практике у нас такого не происходило (пользуемся LTS).

Answer (score 2):

Для запуска чего-либо в фоновом режиме в Linux можно использовать команду
nohup "you_command" &

При выходе из консоли данный процесс будет продолжать работать.

Comment: nohup, а также tmux, screen -- это совершенно неадекватный способ развёртывания веб-приложения на vps. `runserver` это сервер, который может быть использован исключительно для разработки и тестирования, но не для готового сайта. Вместо этого можно использовать уже упомянутые apache+mod_wsgi или nginx+gunicorn.